# SignalR longPolling with GET method and application/json Content-Type causes security warnings

Tags: signalr

Our Third Party security software is being triggered by an apparent mismatch between a header of GET and a Content-Type of application/json.

```
Payload not allowed (Content-Type header not allowed for this method)

/signalr/poll
transport=longPolling&messageId=...&clientProtocol=1.4&etc
application/json; charset=UTF-8
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1;Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

Is this a known issue or have I done something silly?

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 0):

Although largely superfluous, it is the default behaviour of SignalR to send a Content-Type header with GET method Http requests.

Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

I have confirmed this with a small SignalR test program and Fiddler.

As far as I can tell, our Third Party Security software is just being a little overeager.